# How to train for fcn using my own images?

Tags: caffe

I have a problem to train for *FCN* with `caffe`.

I prepared my `images(original image data, segmented image data). 
eg).jpg`.

Then, I want to convert my data to `lmdb` using `convert_imageset.exe`, but its format is `image(array)_label(int)`. But my data is `image(array)_label(array)`.

How to convert own images for *FCN*?

Answer (score 0):

Edit convert_imageset.exe sources to handle your desired format - it's in caffe/tools/convert_imageset.cpp